# Unable to open Xwindows application like Xterm Xclcok

Tags: ssh, x11, forwarding

I am able to ssh into Google VM using Putty. I have been using Putty for X11 forwarding into other linux systems (not on cloud) and use the xterm and xclock. However, while trying on Google VM I get the error

```
user$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

When I do

```
user$ echo $DISPLAY
```

I get empty space which means display is not set. 
I did 
$DISPLAY=localhost.0:0

as well few other options and was able to set the DISPLAY variable accordingly but I still get the error

```
user$ DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
user$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:0.0
user$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

Also, for other systems I never have had to set the DISPLAY variable. Not sure why I have to do so here. 
Please let me know what the problem is.

Thanks in advance for your help